What are standing waves?
What are standing waves? I'm new to wave mechanics and I don't seem to be able to understand why standing waves form. My specific doubt is how do they form and why do they form?
Some intuition might help in understanding about them.

The irony is that standing waves are THE natural waves. Your specific problem needs to be clarified or the question is unanswerable. At least the reason for the electrons is intuitive: the solutions for the Schrodinger equation describing the electrons are stationary state wavefunctions.

Please narrow this down to a more specific question.

Well, standing wave doesn't go anywhere, does it? ;) If you fix two parts of a string and pluck the string, it vibrates on the spot. Broadly speaking, standing wave will form if you have this fixed points beyond which the wave cannot escape and reflects back to the other fixation point.

The first harmonic seems natural and intuitive but the subsequent harmonics are not that intuitive to me
